# Alternative dataIndex values in gridPanel column

Tags: extjs

I have a gridPanel with the following column:

```
header:        'Current plan',
                        tooltip:       'Current plan',
                        dataIndex:     'plan_id',
                        editor:      new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                           allowBlank:          true,
                           typeAhead:           true,
                           triggerAction:       'all',
                           lazyRender:          true,
                           mode:                'local',
                           valueNotFoundText:   'no data',
                           valueField:          'id',
                           displayField:        'text',
                           store:               new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                              fields:  ['id', 'text'],
                              data: [
                                 ['1', 'Plan one'],
                                 ['2', 'Plan two'],
                                 ['3',  'Plan three'],
                                 ['4',  'Plan four']
                              ]
                           })
                        }),
```

So when I edit this field in column - I get "Plan one", "Plan two", "Plan three", "Plan four" as values to choose, when I choose them - dataIndex is set to 1-2-3-4 and displayed in column field like that.
What I want is dataIndex field to stay 1-2-3-4 values (since it's ones I use in backend), but I want them to show up in my column field like "Plan one", "Plan two" and so on.

How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with

```
renderer: function(dataIndex){
                            switch(dataIndex)
                            {
                               case '1':
                                 return 'Plan one';
                                 break;
                               case '2':
                                 return 'Plan two';
                                 break;
                               case '3':
                                 return 'Plan three';
                                 break;
                               case '4':
                                 return 'Plan four';
                                 break;
                            }
                         },
```

in column model.

Answer (score 1):

Better use this code :

```
var comboBoxRenderer = function(combo) {
  return function(value) {
    var idx = combo.store.find(combo.valueField, value);
    var rec = combo.store.getAt(idx);
    return (rec === null ? '' : rec.get(combo.displayField) );
  };
}
```